# Sharepoint to Outlook again!

Tags: list, outlook, office, sharepoint-online

I have created a new column in my SharePoint contact list. How do I push this new column to Outlook contact list, I can see all the standard columns but not the one just created.

Comment: The reason I, personally, don't integrate Outlook and SharePoint Calendars unless I'm forced to is that Outlook can't read or write to any custom columns/metadata set up in SharePoint. I haven't tried it with contacts, but would guess they follow the same principle.

Comment: @ErinL - you are correct, you should place that in the answer column instead of comment.

Answer (score 0):

The reason I, personally, don't integrate Outlook and SharePoint Calendars unless I'm forced to is that Outlook can't read or write to any custom columns/metadata set up in SharePoint. I haven't tried it with contacts, but would guess they follow the same principle.